# How to manage multiple outputs from a `with_outputs` in a PTransform

Tags: python, apache-beam

## Background

Using Apache Beam's Python SDK, I am trying to reroute errors that may occur by creating `DoFn`s like the following:

```py
class AddField(DoFn):
    """Add field(s) to an element in a dictionary."""

    def __init__(self, fail_tag: str = "fail"):
        super().__init__()
        self.fail_tag = fail_tag

    def process(
        self, element: dict[str, Any], **fields
    ) -> Iterable[dict[str, Any]] | Iterable[pvalue.TaggedOutput]:
        if len(fields) == 0 or not isinstance(element, dict):
            yield element # This manages if it the element is already an error from a previous step
        else:
            failure = None
            for name, val in fields.items():
                if name in element:
                    failure = Failure(
                        pipeline_step="AddField",
                        element=element,
                        exception=ValueError(
                            f'Field "{name}" already exists in "{element}".'
                        ),
                    )
                    break
                element[name] = val
            if failure is None:
                yield element
            else:
                yield pvalue.TaggedOutput(self.fail_tag, failure)
```

## Good Examples

Then I have some `PTransform`s that are using `DoFn`s like the `AddField` above:

```py
class PubSubRead(PTransform):
    """Read from messages PubSub, capture timestamp, and load as a dict."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        subscription: str,
        timestamp_fields: tuple[str, ...],
        subscription_field: str = "subscription_name",
        fail_tag: str = FAIL_TAG,
        success_tag: str = SUCCESS_TAG,
        windowing_timestamp_field: str = "time_created",
        **pubsub_configs,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.fail_tag = fail_tag
        self.subscription = subscription
        self.subscription_field = subscription_field
        self.success_tag = success_tag
        self.timestamp_fields = timestamp_fields
        self.pubsub_configs = (
            PUBSUB_CONFIGS
            | pubsub_configs
            | {"subscription": subscription, "topic": None}
        )
        self.friendly_subscription = self.subscription.split("/")[-1]
        self.windowing_timestamp_field = windowing_timestamp_field

    def expand(self, pval: pvalue.PValue) -> PCollection[dict[str, Any]]:
        return (
            pval.pipeline
            | f"Read: {self.friendly_subscription}"
            >> ReadFromPubSub(**self.pubsub_configs).with_output_types(PubsubMessage)
            | "Decode JSON Message"
            >> ParDo(JsonLoad(self.fail_tag))
            .with_outputs(self.fail_tag, main=self.success_tag)
            .with_output_types(tuple[pvalue.TaggedOutput, dict])
            | "Add subscription"
            >> ParDo(AddField(self.fail_tag), subscription_name=self.subscription)
            .with_outputs(self.fail_tag, main=self.success_tag)
            .with_output_types(tuple[pvalue.TaggedOutput, dict])
            | "Add timestamp(s)"
            >> GetTimestamps(*self.timestamp_fields).with_output_types(
                tuple[pvalue.TaggedOutput, dict]
            )
            | f"Tag {self.windowing_timestamp_field} as windowing timestamp"
            >> ParDo(TagTimestamp(self.windowing_timestamp_field)).with_output_types(
                tuple[pvalue.TaggedOutput, dict]
            )
        )
```

For brevity, I am not including any other `DoFn`s besides `AddField`, but they are all structured similarly -- splitting out the error -- except in cases where an error is not possible.

## Problem

The `PTransform` above works fine because it is *starting with* just the pipeline object. But I then have a `PTransform` similar to the one above, but trying to write to a BigQuery table.

I cannot figure out how I should structure it, though.  It starts with:

```py
class BigQueryWrite(PTransform):
    """Write to BigQuery, first converting data types as needed."""

    def __init__(
        self,
        table_path: str,
        timestamp_fields: tuple[str, ...],
        fail_tag: str = FAIL_TAG,
        success_tag: str = SUCCESS_TAG,
        **bq_configs,
    ):
        super().__init__()
        self.fail_tag = fail_tag
        self.success_tag = success_tag
        self.table_path = table_path
        self.friendly_table = self.table_path.split(".")[-1]
        self.timestamp_fields = timestamp_fields
        self.bq_configs = BIGQUERY_CONFIGS | bq_configs

    def expand(self, pcoll: pvalue.PValue): # I'm not sure what type `pcoll` should be. I've tried it as a `PCollection`.
        return (
            pcoll # <== This is where it is failing, error below
            | "Convert to BQ friendly types"
            >> ConvertToBQFriendlyTypes(
                timestamp_fields=self.timestamp_fields,
                fail_tag=self.fail_tag,
                success_tag=self.success_tag,
            )
.
.
.
```

## Error

But as I write above, it is already failing at the line where I call `pcoll`.  There call stack is long, but the key part is:

```
TypeError: Unexpected output type: [[<apache_beam.pvalue._InvalidUnpickledPCollection object at 0x7f70445c68d0>, <apache_beam.pvalue._InvalidUnpickledPCollection object at 0x7f70445c6bd0>], []]
```

It's clear that somehow I am saying that something has multiple output types when in fact it doesn't. But I'm not sure how I am supposed to handle all of these `ParDo`s with multiple output: once multiple outputs are possible, don't I have to keep track of them for the rest of the pipeline?

## Calling Code

Here is the code that is calling these transforms:

```py
    messages: PCollection[dict[str, Any]] = (
        pipeline
        | f"Read:\n{friendly_sub}"
        >> PubSubRead(
            subscription=options.subscription,
            timestamp_fields=("time_created", "time_processed", "publish_time"),
        ) # <== Should I be adding a `with_outputs` here, too? That is not a `PTransform` method.
    _raw_write = (
        messages
        | "Map to Raw Schema"
        >> ParDo(RemapFields(), pubsub_to_raw_schema)
        .with_outputs(fail_tag, main=success_tag)
        .with_output_types(tuple[pvalue.TaggedOutput, dict])
        | f"Write: {friendly_raw_table}"
        >> BigQueryWrite(
            table_path=raw_table,
            timestamp_fields=("time_created", "time_processed", "publish_time"),
        )
    )
```

## Question

So, it seems like I am somehow adding an extra `with_outputs`, but **I don't understand how I *should* tie together `PTransform`s, if I want to keep the `PCollection`s with both of the tagged types**.

I know I could separate the tags and process each tag differently, but I'd like to make some general, best practice solutions that can serve many pipelines. So I want a general solution that can manage any input that might already have errors, so I want to keep processing both of the tags throughout the pipeline.